# Get an object in Json String of different objects

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json String that hava objects A, B, C like this:

```
[{
"attr 1" : "val 1",
"attr 2" : "val 2",
  "B": {
    "attr 1": "val 1"
    "attr 2": "val 2"
    "C": {
      "attr 1": "val 1"
      "attr 2": "val 2"
    }
   }
}]
```

I have questions:
1. How can I split the string to get the data of 3 classes?
2. How can I get the data of class A?
3. How can I get the data of class B?
4. How can I get the data of class C?

Comment: Ever heard of Json Libraries such as https://newtonsoft.com?

Comment: Where is object "A"?

Comment: Object with 2 attributes that is after the root

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON you posted is not quite valid as it's missing some commas but with that fixed:

```
[{
        "attr 1": "val 1",
        "attr 2": "val 2",
        "B": {
            "attr 1": "val 1",
            "attr 2": "val 2",
            "C": {
                "attr 1": "val 1",
                "attr 2": "val 2"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

if you are using Visual Studio - you can **Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON As Classes** in a new file which will give you:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
    public C C { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can remove the class `Rootobject` as if you try to deserialize to this class - it will fail as there is no property JSON key called `Property1`.

You can then use `https://www.newtonsoft.com/json` to deserialize your JSON string to your new object:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(json);

var classB = obj[0].B;
var classC = obj[0].B.C;
```

I'd recommend renaming `Class1` to something more meaningful!

**Edit**: You will also need to decorate your class properties with the `[JsonProperty]` attribute as your JSON keys contain spaces i.e:

```
public class Class1
{
    [JsonProperty("attr 1")]
    public string Attr1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attr 2")]
    public string Attr2 { get; set; }

    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

and so on...

Comment: I get it. But how to add newtonsoft.com?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json You can install through NuGet package manager `Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console > Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 12.0.2` or right click on your project in Solution Explorer > `Manage NuGet Packages` and search for Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Okay, I get it. But one more question: I have a web api that return json string But the json string that return a string with a format that is on my question. So how can I get the json string of only one object?

Comment: `var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj[0].B)` should give you `"B": {
    "attr 1": "val 1"
    "attr 2": "val 2"
    "C": {
      "attr 1": "val 1"
      "attr 2": "val 2"
    }
   }`